# Javafx Hyperlink: Style to influence visibility of 'underline' of link

Tags: javafx

I want that the 'underline' of a hyperlink in JavaFx is always visible. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using css like this

```
link.setStyle("-fx-underline: true");
```

Or you could create a css file if you want to style your link more