# JavaFX label text Underline Spacing with Css

Tags: css, javafx, spacing, underline

I have Forget password label in JavaFX application that I applied **underline** on it.
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQqti.jpg)
I know this isn't possible to do with a basic property, but instead I have applied the following CSS to the label and I don't know how to set **Spacing** between the text and the underline
[css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HqWl.png)

Comment: Don't screenshot text like css.  Put the text as text in the question, formatted as code (indent four spaces).

Answer (score 0):

**Specifying the underline offset**

JavaFX css does not have a [text-underline-offset](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-underline-offset/) attribute as far as I know. You could display the link in a WebView and configure the offset using web css rather than JavaFX css, but I wouldn't really recommend that.

JavaFX [private implementation uses an underline offset](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/86b854dc367fb32743810716da5583f7d59208f8/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/sg/prism/NGText.java#L174), but that is not public API and cannot be controlled via public API, so I don't think that helps you.

**Related info on clickable text (hyperlinks)**

For clickable text, you should use a [Hyperlink](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Hyperlink.html) rather than a Label.

See the [Hyperlink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/hyperlink.htm) tutorial and [css](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/fdc88341f1df8fb9c99356ada54b25124b77ea6e/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css#L824).

Hyperlink, by default only displays an underline on hover, to have it always displayed, see the related question:

- [Javafx Hyperlink: Style to influence visibility of 'underline' of link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832260/javafx-hyperlink-style-to-influence-visibility-of-underline-of-link)